# В чем разница между import и checkout командами?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Только учусь пользоваться svn (сам до этого использовал git). Случайно импортировал репозиторий в пустую папку (посредством import команды). Теперь читаю документацию, и там сказано что лучше использовать checkout. В чем конкретно разница между этими командами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался прост. Я просто перепутал значение этой команды. Изначально я думал, что импорт выполняет копирование хранилища (рабочее место) в пустую папку. Как раз нет, в документации сказано, что эта команда копирует содержимое! папки в хранилище. Все что я наблюдал, было просто обновление рабочего места (которое загружалось в пустую папку) и все (так как папка пуста, то импорта не происходило).

Выводы: никогда для подобных целей не использовать команду импорта (использовать команду checkout). Более того, даже после такого трюка (команда import), содержимое папки не будет рабочим местом (для этого придется снова извлечь файлы с хранилища!)